# Overclock settings aren't being applied after some time

Tags: gpu, desktop-computer, overclocking, msi-afterburner

I have a Gigabyte GT 730 and I recently overclocked it so that I can play heavier games. I set the Core Clock at 870MHz and the memory clock at 980MHz. So even though these settings get the job done and give me approximately 150 FPS in League of Legends, after a few hours the FPS drops to 30-40 making the game unplayable. Basically the oc settings stop working :P. I tried opening the MSI Afterburner and reapplying the oc settings but nothing changes unless I restart my pc. Any help would be much appreciated.[My OC Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTTzq.png)

Comment: The first thing i would do is reset the overclock, typically you can't overclock on air, resulting more than a few FPS increase anyways.  What you describe, at least to me, is an unstable OC

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your graphics card, I used MSI Afterburner on my previous card Geforce GT 730 not long ago, mine has Core base clock at 910 MHz, and I can't even add 200MHz without it crashing.

I used GpuTest on that card and the results were ugly, so I replaced it with Geforce GTX 1050 Ti, and now only the Piano test has beaten my card, this card is still not top notch, however it should be enough to handle games from before 2015 at 1080p and games after 2015 at 1080p at low settings.

So unfortunately, the hard truth is, overclocking can't really make your games run faster if your graphics card is low-end, do you really expect MSI Afterburner can make your GPU run continuously at Core frequency at 870 MHz and memory at 980 MHz without frying your Graphics card?

If MSI Afterburner can do that, then all the people buy better graphics card are fools, why should they buy better cards if MSI Afterburner can magically boost their cards by hundreds of megahertz's and achieve the same results for free?

Graphics card generate huge amounts of heat, what do you think those fans on the cards are used for? The more calculating power the more heat it generates. Modern CPU's and GPU's have hundreds of millions of transistors over a small area, that switches on and off billions (what Giga- means) of times per second, this is how most of the heat is generated, and faster clock frequency means more electricity consumption, and physics dictates the usage of electricity creates heat, heat dissipation is the factor that limits us to 5 GHz CPU's.

Modern GPU's and CPU's have builtin automatic thermal protection that automatically disconnects power if its temperature is too high, because GPU's and CPU's have an upper limit of temperature at which it can safely operate, beyond the temperature the circuits will be damaged by the heat.

You really shouldn't try to overclock Geforce GT 730, that card doesn't even have a connector to the PSU, overclocking make your card consume more power, and the power provided by PCIe slot isn't enough.

You should upgrade your GPU.

---

I found it strange that my Msi Afterburner window is different from yours:

[image]

Yours has no OC at the top left corner, and no indicators, and yours' sliders adjust total frequency rather than mine's boosted frequency...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I borrowed this card because I saw videos on youtube in which the GT 730 run League of Legends at 100 fps. When my card is not overclocked it isn't running at 100% so I had 30 fps and this was the reason I overclocked it in the first place.